# Rinkeby failure with web3.py -- Could not format value '0x...' as field 'extraData'

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, web3.py, proof-of-authority

I am trying to connect to Rinkeby using web3.py. But when I call a method, like `w3.version.node`, it throws an exception ending in:

> ```
> ...
>   File "/home/hacker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/utils/formatters.py", line 69, in apply_formatters_to_dict
>     raise type(exc)("Could not format value %r as field %r" % (item, key)) from exc
> ValueError: Could not format value '0x{LONG_HEX}' as field 'extraData'
> ```

*(Where `LONG_HEX` is a **lot** of hex characters, like 194)*

How do I fix my connection to get block data?

Versions:

- `geth` 1.8.2
- `web3.py` v4.0.0-beta.13

*Note: In addition to the Rinkeby network, I get this same exception after connecting to a node started with `geth --dev`*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Insert a special middleware in web3.py v5+ to handle geth-style proof-of-authority, [like this](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority):

> ```
> py> from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider
>
> # connect to the default geth --dev IPC location
> py> w3 = Web3(IPCProvider('/tmp/geth.ipc'))
>
> py> from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
>
> # inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
> py> w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
>
> # confirm that the connection succeeded
> py> w3.version.node
> 'Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4'
> ```

## Why is `geth_poa_middleware` necessary?

A slightly modified version of the [web3.py docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/middleware.html#why-is-geth-poa-middleware-necessary):

> There is no strong community consensus on a single Proof-of-Authority (PoA) standard yet. Some nodes have successful experiments running, though. One is go-ethereum (geth), which uses a prototype PoA for it’s development mode and the Rinkeby test network.
>
> Unfortunately, the prototype does deviate from the yellow paper specification, which constrains the `extraData` field in each block to a maximum of 32-bytes. Geth’s PoA uses more than 32 bytes, which causes a validation failure in web3.py. This middleware modifies the block data to shorten `extraData` a bit before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to previous answer: In web3py version 5.x.x you have to change it this way:

```
    # inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
    w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

to this:

```
    # inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

I mean, `middleware_stack` was renamed to: `middleware_onion`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the improvement! When improving an existing answer, it is better structured as a comment to that answer.

Comment: Right, but you have to have 50pts of reputation for that, which I don't ! :-) (cruel world) Indeed, what is optimal, just realized, I seem to be able to actually _edit_ your answer.. next time.. lesson learned.