# ImportError: cannot import name geth_poa_middleware

Tags: web3.py

- Web3.py version 3.15.0
- Python: Python 3.5.2
- OS: linux

---

I have followed @carver 's answer related to [Rinkeby failure with web3.py — Could not format value '0x…' as field 'extraData'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44131/4575) related to `web3.exceptions.ValidationError: The field extraData is 97 bytes, but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA chain. Refer http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority for more details.`:

**Code:**

```
from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider
# connect to the default geth --dev IPC location
w3 = Web3(IPCProvider('/home/user/POA/private/geth.ipc'))
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware #<===Error occurs

# inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

# confirm that the connection succeeded
w3.version.node
```

---

**Error I am having:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coder.py", line 4, in <module>
    from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
ImportError: cannot import name geth_poa_middleware
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this error (`cannot import name geth_poa_middleware`)?

Comment: Most likely answer is that you are not using the version of web3.py that you expected. From the same environment as you are running `coder.py` run a `pip install -U web3` to get the latest stable version.